# форма <input type="datetime-local">

Tags: html, html5, datetime

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать что б в datetime-local всегда выдавался 24 часовой пояс либо как можно его заменить либо хотя бы изменить стиль данного input [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

просто невсем пользователям понятно что после времени нужно еще вводить am, pm

Comment: пробывал добавить patern непомогло  <input type="datetime-local" name="ddaytime" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ прост. Это не возможно. При крайней необходимости используйте JS.

Comment: если вам не сложно можете написать код или ссылку пожалуйста?

Comment: [Вот](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) не плохая реализация.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что такая запись `<input type="datetime-local"/>` означает что для ввода используется формат времени локальный, заданный в системе пользователя.

Тут ключевое слово локальный.

Со своей стороны не вижу смысла бороться с этим, так как если у пользователя установлен ввод с AM PM то это означает что такой вводи знаком пользователю и он к нему привык.

В любом случаем можно использовать кастомный JavaScript компонент.

Comment: Вы совершенно не правы. Его удалили из рабочего черновика, и переместили в [черновик корректировки](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59284/is-datetime-local-removed-from-html-5-1). Проще говоря его повысили.

Comment: @Vasiliy Rusin возможно, но по той ссылке что я привёл говорят что рабочий код из браузеров убрали. Я просто процитировал, вольным переводом.

Comment: [вот черновик](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140204/forms.html#local-date-and-time-state-%28type=datetime-local%29) не стоит вводит людей в заблуждение. Ваша ссылка это массовая истерия во время перехода черновика.

Comment: @Vasiliy Rusin  хорошо, тогда удаляю эту часть

Comment: @Vasiliy Rusin то что вы привели относится к datetime-local а я писал про datetime, и в моём браузере datetime реально работает как ввод просто строки.

Comment: @Vasiliy Rusin но про массовую истерию думаю вы правы, так что эту часть оставляю удалённой.

Comment: путем не сложных манипуляций поднимаемся чуть выше и видим [datetime](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140204/forms.html#date-and-time-state-(type=datetime))
Я показал на примере `datetime-local` по тому что в ссылке которую вы кидали было сказано что оба отменены. Если не секрет что за браузер? Safari? IE? Старый Firefox?

Comment: @Vasiliy Rusin Yandex browser.

Comment: Неожиданно. Видимо Yandex сам убрал это отображение (или еще не реализовал в своем дизайне) по тому как Chromium поддерживает их раньше всех.

Comment: @Vasiliy Rusin у меня Chrome так же ведёт.

Comment: datetime-local работает и там и там, а просто datetime то же не работает и там и там.

Answer (score 0):

Никаких AM/PM не вижу

```html
<input type="datetime-local"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что у вас в системе стоит 24-х часовой пояс, а у тех у кого стоит 12 часовой у них другой инпут

Comment: @Sergey, И если у них стоит 12 часовой формат, как они могут не знать про am/pm? Вопрос бессмысленный. Браузер выводит отображения в соответствии с тем как предпочтительно это для пользователя.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin я все прекрасно понимаю, но все же хотелось бы изменить, что бы у всех форма выглядела одинаково

Comment: @Sergey, именно из-за таких желаний **нет совершенно никакой возможности сделать отображение *стандартного* поля настраиваемым**. Если вам нужно отойти от спецификации используйте кастомную реализацию на JS.