# Текущая дата и время datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html, html5, время

Нужно что в элементе datetime-local отображалась текущая дата и время типа значения по умолчанию как это реализовать?

```
<input type=datetime-local name='deliverydate' value=''>
```

Comment: отображалась в реальном времени?

Comment: связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/245460/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript?rq=1 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768847/javascript-%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8/768866#768866 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/248660/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8?rq=1

Comment: связанный : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513320/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-input-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-datetime-local-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-utc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5?rq=1 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756351/%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0-input-type-datetime-local?rq=1

Comment: Вы хоть искали в поиске, тут кучу ответов есть включая и на ваш вопрос? Просмотрите указанные ссылки, думаю вы найдете ответ. Дальше рыться не стал, но там еще есть

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=datetime-local name='deliverydate' value=''>


$(document).ready( function() {
$('input[type=datetime-local]').val(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,19));});
```